# Equalizing the length of 3 vectors in R based on a rule

Tags: r, function, vector

Suppose I have the 3 vectors `x`, `y`, and `z` which are of unequal length (*see code below*).

I was wondering how I could have the *last member* of the shorter vectors (*here `x` and `y`*) be repeated such that the 3 vectors always become of equal length whenever they are of unequal length?

For example, in the example below `2` in `x` be repeated 2 times, and `"hi"` in `y` be repeated 3 times.

```
x = c(1, 2) ; y = c("hi") ; z = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Why downvoting? I got a very great answer.

Comment: I was shocked by the downvote!! I guess someone misread your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
foo = function(...){
    ml = list(...)
    L = max(lengths(ml))
    lapply(ml, function(x) c(x, rep(tail(x, 1), L - length(x))))
}
foo(x, y, z)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 2 2

#[[2]]
#[1] "hi" "hi" "hi" "hi"

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: These days you see people to be into weird kinds of art. This is a piece of classic art mate. Cheers.